# How can I retrieve port configs and IDs of a USBxpress serial device from software DLLs?

Tags: ollydbg

I'm new to the coding game. I've been using Ollydbg to try and find the info but it seems it's encrypted. I was hoping I could locate the info so I can program my device to work with the software it's intended for. I was able to find where the process requests the info and sets the info under "names" .text files (Example: ".text _GetDeviceVid" and ".text _SetVid"). Is there a way I can retrieve that info so I can use it to program my device?

Comment: From google _GetDeviceVid takes a guid and returns a guid  set a break on _GetDeviceVid when it breaks look at the stack dump the input set a break point on return address f9 to execute and dump the output guid

Comment: Your instructions are a bit hard to follow without punctuation. I managed to find a guid in my earlier searches but I don't know if it's the right one, and don't know what to do with it now. Does it contain all of the needed info required to program things like product string, manufacturer string, max power, etc?